# How to Change Default Save in Excel to .xlsm type

Tags: excel, save

I have to save a bunch of .xls or text delimited files as .xlsm files so macros can be saved in the file and used in the future. I couldn't find a default file save format in options, so is there a way to set Excel to automatically save as .xlsm?

Excel 2013

Comment: [First](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Change-the-default-file-format-for-saving-workbooks-16318414-f050-40b8-8b17-23ff5f381fb5) google result. Not sure what version you have.

Comment: If my answer helped you can you select it as the answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel 2010:
File --> Options --> Save --> Set the type you want.

You should revise your question to add the version of Excel you are on.

[image: Screen Shot -- Look Here]

Comment: Love the Screen Capture as well.  was about to edit your post and include it myself!

Comment: Ha-ha I'm on mobile so it causes me pain to inset the image as I create the post.  It's easier to go back edit and put the image in.  At least in my opinion.